# how to name a set which subset is not vertex-cut set

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Sorry, this question sounds stupid because it's just like a basic term, but it's difficult for me, as my mother language is Chinese.
Now, i write my paper about graph theory in chinese, and editor ask me to write term to define my question, that "find a set which subset isn't vertex-cut set" is prolix and unprofessional.
thanks.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Is your question on translating (or finding better words for) the question "Find a set that is not a vertex-cut set?"

Comment: Of course, in a graph, I want to choose nodes to place facility. For some limitation, I get a constraint which needs to guarantee any subset of selected nodes cannot divide the graph into two or more disconnected subgraph